# How to change Text in Animation in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I use Animated.Text for change Animation Text but it's not working properly

I also require in animation fade out old text & fade in the new text.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    Dimensions,
    Animated
} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

const win = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class Logo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.tempText = new Animated.Value("Hello");
    }

    componentWillMount () {
        Animated.timing(this.tempText, {
            duration: 5000,
            toValue: "New Text",
        }).start();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <Animated.Text style={{color: "#9b9b9b"}}>
                    {this.tempText}
                </Animated.Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Actual output Get - Change text after 5 Second but it's not working.please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve can be done without using `Animated` at all, and actually, `Animated` isn't intended for this particular use.

Replacing the text can be done with a simple variable, and the text change can be triggered by a `setTimeout`.

Animated is intended for changing a numeric value, not a text value. Think of it this way - if the change is supposed to happen over a 5 second interval, what would the mid-value be?

Do this instead:

```
export default class Logo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {text: "Hello"};
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({text: "New Text"}), 5000);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <Animated.Text style={{color: "#9b9b9b"}}>
                    {this.state.text}
                </Animated.Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the effect you're trying to get? How does a smooth text change look like?

Comment: fade in fade out animation when new text Change

Comment: You didn't mention that anywhere in the question! You'll need to use an `Animated.Value` for the `opacity` style property of the text element.

Answer (score 1):

My example with smoothly opacity animation.
Sorry, without fadeIn, fadeOut.

```
const inputRange = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const AnimatedText = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Text);
    const animationProps = {
      duration: 500,
      easing: Easing.out(Easing.linear),
      isInteraction: false,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    };

class Onboarding extends PureComponent {
  activeDot = 0;
  animationDot = new Animated.Value(0);

  toggleOnButton = () => {
      Animated.timing(this.animationDot, {
        toValue: this.activeDot + 1,
        ...animationProps,
      }).start((endState) => {
        if (endState.finished) {
          this.activeDot = this.activeDot + 1;
        }
      });
  }

  renderButton = () => {
    const opacityNext = this.animationDot.interpolate({
      inputRange,
      outputRange: [1, 1, 1, 0]
    });
    const opacityGetStarted = this.animationDot.interpolate({
      inputRange,
      outputRange: [0, 0, 0, 1]
    });
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.toggleOnButton}>
        <AnimatedText style={[styles.buttonText, { opacity: opacityNext }]}>
          Next
        </AnimatedText>
        <AnimatedText style={[styles.buttonText, {
            top: normalize(isIOS ? 12 : 8), position: 'absolute', opacity: opacityGetStarted
          }]}
        >
          Get started
        </AnimatedText>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```